# Which shop has more workers registered than its actual capacity?

Tags: mysql

Which shop has more workers registered than its actual capacity ?

I have three tables

```
Shop(shopid,shopname,shopcapacity)
Workers(workerid,name,address)
Registration(regid,workerid,shopid,fromdate,todate)
```

I tried below queries, it works for one shop which has more workers registered than its capacity – but its not working for every shop, can anyone suggest ?

```
select shopname AS ShopName, 
shopcapacity AS ShopCapacity,
count(r.shopid) AS RegisteredWorkers
from shop f
inner join registration r
on f.shopid = r.shopid
where f.shopcapacity <  ANY ( select count(shopid) 
from registration
group by shopid)
group by r.shopid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    shopname
FROM
    shop
    LEFT OUTER JOIN registration reg on 
        shop.shopid = reg.shopid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN workers on
        reg.workerid = workers.workerid
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN reg.fromdate and reg.todate
HAVING count(distinct workerid) > shopcapacity
GROUP BY shopname, shopcapacity
```

I added the bit with the `WHERE CURDATE()...` because it seemed like your `registration` table was time sensitive.

At any rate, the `HAVING` statement here will check to see if the count of workers currently registered is greater than the `shopcapacity`. The GROUP BY insures that the DB is aggregating across `shopname` and the `shopcapacity`.

Comment: I tried this its not working! , some syntax errors , I even moved having to the end of the statements.

Comment: right syntax to use near (distinct workerid) > shopcapacity , check MYsql manual

Comment: Error : right syntax to use near (distinct workerid) > shopcapacity , check MYsql manual

Comment: Drop the `distinct` bit since it's almost definitely not necessary. See if that clears things up.